# XML parsing in a DB2 native stored procedure using XMLTABLE

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, db2

I am a new DB development. 
I have to create a procedure that accepts XML as input,

- parses it
- validates
- gives out XML as output

I am stuck while parsing the XML. 
I have used `XMLTABLE`.
 Below is the sample XML that my proc would consume.

```
<root>
 <request>requestid1</request>
 <source>source1</source>
 <accountlist>
   <account>123456789</account>
   <account>234567890</account>
 </accountlist>
</root>

 CREATE PROCEDURE XMLPARSE ( 
 IN IN_REQ XML, 
 OUT OUT_REQ XML
 )

 DECLARE V_REQUEST CHAR(10) DEFAULT ' ';
 DECLARE V_SOURCE  CHAR(10) DEFAULT ' ';
 DECLARE V_ACCOUNT CHAR(09) DEFAULT ' ';

 DECLARE CURSOR1 CURSOR FOR

  SELECT X.* FROM
  XMLTABLE (‘$d/root/accountlist/account' PASSING IN_REQ as "d"
  COLUMNS
  "request" CHAR(10) PATH ‘../request’,
  "source"  CHAR(10) PATH '../source',
  "account" CHAR(9)  PATH '.') AS X;


  FETCH CURSOR1 INTO V_REQUEST, V_SOURCE, V_ACCOUNT;

  Rest of the logic to process the above obtained data
```

1) First, i was looking for a way to parse all the XML elements using a single XMLTABLE operation using a cursor like above but it is not working, i am not able to fetch "request" and "source" despite of giving the PATH from root i.e. '../', i am expecting the cursor to run two times giving result set as below. Is anything missing?

```
 **request**     **source**     **account**
 requestid1       source1        123456789
 requestid1       source1        234567890
```

2) If the above approach is not correct, can anyone please suggest the correct one to parse XML in a DB2 native stored procedure.

Comment: Are you on Db2 LUW or z/OS? What is done with the result of the procedure and how will it look like? Maybe you don't need any and use a regular table. Can you use XML Schema and validate a doc with it?

Comment: The parent element of `account` is `accountlist`, not `root`; adjust your `PATH` specifications.

Comment: @data_henrik, i am on DB2 LUW and i cannot use a normal table, my procedure has to consume an XML and i have to extract each element from the nodes and give those as output. So taking the above example,my output should return request1, source1, 123456789 and 234567890 as OUT parameters.

Comment: @mustaccio,                                                                                   
I am able to get both the accounts back from the above query but i am not getting request and source. Is there any other command apart from XMLTABLE through which i can extract elements from an XML?

Answer (score 2):

The following returns the values you want.

```
SELECT X.* 
FROM TABLE(VALUES
  XMLPARSE(document '<root>
 <request>requestid1</request>
 <source>source1</source>
 <accountlist>
   <account>123456789</account>
   <account>234567890</account>
 </accountlist>
</root>') )  AS IN(IN_REQ)
 , XMLTABLE ('$d/root/accountlist/account' PASSING IN_REQ as "d"
  COLUMNS
  "request" CHAR(10) PATH '../../request',
  "source"  CHAR(10) PATH '../../source',
  "account" CHAR(9)  PATH '.') AS X;
```

which returns

```
 request        source      account
 ----------     ----------  ---------
 requestid1     source1     123456789
 requestid1     source1     234567890
```

I.e. you needed to go up two levels (to root) to then get `request` and `source` in the XPath for those columns.

(BTW you might find that you don't need a cursor to perform your later logic, you might be able to do all the work in a singe query

Also/alternatively, consider using Db2 features to validate XML against an XML schema 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.xml.doc/doc/c0023539.html
)